In Spring Webflux, is it thread safe to initialized a variable and use it later inside a Mono pipeline?
Say I have a @RestController with a @GetMapping with the following mono pipeline. MyRequest and MyResponse just has a String field called id.
Is it correct to use id into the Mono pipeline without having the id variable be passed into the reactive chain?
Because Webflux uses Reactive Netty which uses event loops is it possible for one request to come in and have id be 123 and a second request with id abc. Is it possible for the request to have receive the wrong id?
    @PostMapping
    public Mono<MyResponse> handler(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
        String id = myRequest.getId();

        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            // Step 1: Does stuff
            return "stuff";
        }).map(s -> {
            // Step 2: Do some more stuff
            return new MyResponse(id);
        });

    }

I have seen that sometimes the MyResponse(id) doesn't give me back the id of was sent in the initial request.  The id is from a different request. There is continuous traffic flowing through the application, not just on a single request.

There should be no problem with your example snippet. Problems might arise if you updating a mutable object (i.e. do something like myRequest.setId("a value") somewhere in your code. How do you check the id in MyResponse ? Do you print a log that contains both request and response ids ?

The mismatch is observed from the client side.
We do log, but it's hard to say which request it came from since the id field is what we use to identify, but if it's getting swapped with another request then we can't tell.

Ok, I'll accept the answer. I think it was just we were using a static reference that caused our problems.

Maybe you can use reactor.util.context.Context with it you can pass your variables with current Publisher.
String id = myRequest.getId();
Context context = Context.of("id", id);

And in flow you can get id back from it with using:
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            // Step 1: Does stuff
            return "stuff";
        }).map(s -> {
            // Step 2: Do some more stuff
            return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> new MyResponse((String) context.get("id")));
        });


